# Run KVM inside LXC container

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, kvm, lxc, nested-virtualization

I have a baremetal server with Debian. Iside it I have KVM-based VMs and LXC containers. Now I am searching a solution to run KVM inside LXC container.

Comment: I don't think that can even be a thing

Comment: It's possible to run KVM in chroot, it's even possible to run KVM in VM on top of KVM, and even KVM-on-VM-on-KVM-on-VM-on-KVM, if CPU supports it. 
I, pesonally, run KVM on VM on top of KVM on VM on top of KVM, emulating a big network with CISCOs and Mikrotiks in VMs and some other emulated routers and switches.
So, why not KVM in LXC? I'm sure it's possible.

Comment: OK. I'll back out. I just didn't think you would be able to run KVM inside a container - to my mind that more likely to end up being KVM on the container's kernel (i.e. the host)

Comment: You have to figure out what's usually disabled in a container that needs to be enabled for proper operations. Obviously access to `/dev/kvm`.